# "Inconsistent accessibility: base class is less accessible than class"

Tags: c#, parent-child, parent, abstract

Doing an assignment that a teacher has pretty much wrote us step by step how to do, I've had these 4 errors for a while but just ignored them.

Basically i have a parent class Menus with child classes PauseMenu, MainMenu, DifficultyMenu, and HelpMenu. The four errors i am getting say that the parent class is less accessible than the child class. Menu is abstract while the child menus are public, as instructed.

```
    #region Constructors
    protected Menu(MenuName menuName, Texture2D background, Rectangle drawRectangle)
    {
        this.menuName = menuName;
        this.background = background;
        this.drawRectangle = drawRectangle;
    }
    public Menu()
    {

    }
    #endregion
```

our professor specifically said to add a public constructor with no parameters specifically for this reason, but my IDE is still telling me that its wrong.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is the constructor for the main menu

```
public MainMenu(Rectangle drawRectangle)
    : base(MenuName.MainMenu, SpriteDictionary.GetSprite("mainMenuBackground"), drawRectangle)
{}
```

here is the declaration of the class

```
namespace WackyPong.Menus
{
    public abstract class Menu
    {
        //all my code
    }
```

Comment: What access specifier is `Menu` (the class) given? *Hint*: I'm guessing its `internal` or not present.

Comment: It's not the *constructor* accessibility which is here - it's the *class* accessibility. So you should be checking the class declarations, neither of which you've included here.

Comment: Note that `abstract` is *not* an access specifier. A non-nested class is either `public` or `internal`, with the latter being the default.

Comment: public abstract class Menu    changed it to that and its still not working

Comment: It still might not be working, but it's not for the same reason.

Comment: I'm guessing the error changed; what is it now?

Comment: Any ideas on whereabouts my issue would lie? `public abstract class Menu` is how its declared now. Its the same four errors

Comment: Do your classes actually inherit from `Menu`?

Comment: if by `public class MainMenu : Menu` then yes

Comment: Clean and rebuild. With the access modifier changed, there is no way you should be getting the same errors.

Comment: rebuilt it and its removed the errors, thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

This error is usually related to class accessibility, as mentioned in comments. This can cause a problem since you expose a derived type via `public` but not the base type, and thus typecasting and inherited members enter a grey area of "do we expose these to other dlls?" - an area eliminated by this error refusing to build your project.

Seeing that the abstract base class is indeed public, have you made sure this applied to all of the types you've created? I note the use of a `MenuName` object in the constructor.

Note that this error will also show up if you have any public properties, fields, or methods which take or return types which are not publicly exposed - the compiler again enters that area of "the member is exposed, but the type included in its signature isn't."

Comment: menuName is just an enumeration, and yes it is public